# Node.js, Mongodb, Monk, PapaParse, Bluebird, DB won't update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bluebird, monk

So my goal -> write a script to pull data out of a csv and dump it in my database. So everything seems to be working, except that I can't get the process to properly exit without erasing whatever data (or not writing it all) to the database.

```
db.then((db) => {
    console.log('connected to db');
    const creators = db.get('creators');

    let files = fs.readdirAsync(folder)
    .catch(err => {
        exitOnErr(err, 'error reading directory');
    })
    .map(filename => {
        return processFile(filename)
        .then(content => {
            return Papa.parsePromise(content);
        })
        .then(results => {
            db_add(results, creators);
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Completed parsing files..');
        /* close db and exit the process -> if I do this here,
           then everything exits without doing anything, but if
           I let the process keep running, then the database
           gets properly updated */
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    exitOnErr(err, 'error connecting to db');
});
```

Where is the proper place to close the database and exit the process? Having trouble figuring out where to fit it in the scheme of promises here.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Updated code:

```
db.then((db) => {
    console.log('connected to db');
    const creators = db.get('creators');

    return fs.readdirAsync(folder)
    .catch(err => {
        exitOnErr(err, 'error reading directory');
    })
    .map(filename => {
        return processFile(filename)
        .then(content => {
            return Papa.parsePromise(content);
        })
        .then(results => {
            return db_add(results, creators);
        });
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    exitOnErr(err, 'error connecting to db');
}).then(() => {
    console.log('Completed parsing files...');
    closeAndExit(0);
});
```

Wasn't properly returning promises up the chain.